# using custom font path on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, next.js, fonts, wordpress-gutenberg, next.js13

I have a custom website font on a storybook dist folder called assets.

In the same repository I have a wordpress website where i'm using Gutenberg Builder to build the preview page.

Wordpress is loading the font on the custom block pointing to example.com/fonts/customFont/customFont.ttf, i want to overwrite this path to use the one on my dist folder and in the future host the all application (storybook Design System on a npm package, nextjs on the frontend, and wordpress as a CMS) on the same place.

Right now i'm having the font returning 404 on the wrong path.

is there a way to overwrite the path on the font?

i've already tried to alter the functions.php file without success using wp_enqueue_script.

right now i'm having this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WStAr.png)

using wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.